# Different git repo for Configure Build Variants

Tags: android, git, build

I have an `app` with different `version`.

But every `version` have different  Git repository.
So please let me know how we can manage that every `build` `variant` have different `repository`.

Comment: @Amal thanks for edit :)

Comment: Thanks for -1 who has done this :).  I really appreciating your efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have different tags or branches per version, not different repositories.

From the same repo, you would then use [`git worktree`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree) in order to clone the repo once, but checkout the repo multiple times: see "[Multiple working directories with Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30185564/6309)".
That way, you have different folders, each one with a different version of your project.

Since only the name/color/logo are changing, you would need:

- one repo with all the common code
- one configuration file with the right values for name/color/logo per environment
- one way for your code to detect in which environment it is deployed: your code you then pick the right value from the config file.

The point is: one project, one Git repo: See the [12 factors app](https://12factor.net/) (in particular, the [Config section](https://12factor.net/config)).

Comment: actually problem is i have already created the 4 projects, which are same only color ,logo and name is change , and they have different git repo. and projects are live. Recently i have heard about the Build variant so need a solutions for this